# set tikz path length automatically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]

    \node[rectangle, draw] (R) at (0,0){$R$};
    \draw node[xor gate, right of=R](X){};

    % How to automatically set this condition such that the end point touches border of R?
    \path[black, draw] (X.input 1) -- ($(X.input 1)+(-.3,0)$); 

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I need help to set the path joining `R` and `X`, such that it touches `R`.

Comment: what do you want to express with that drawing? I kind of feel, that you doing this wrong from the start, when you know what I mean.

Comment: @Julian_W This is just an example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
\path[black, draw] (X.input 1) -- (X.input 1-|R.east);
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]

  \node[rectangle, draw] (R) at (0,0){$R$};
  \draw node[xor gate, right of=R](X){};

  \path[black, draw] (X.input 1) -- (X.input 1-|R.east);% <- changed

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```